# How to implement a Move action in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, implementation, skaction

SpriteKit has an action called `.moveBy(x:y:duration:)`. I wanted to try and implement this action myself and found it surprisingly difficult.

```swift
static func moveX(by amount: CGFloat, duration: TimeInterval) -> SKAction {
    let speed = amount / duration
    var lastElapsedTime = 0.0
    return .customAction(withDuration: duration) { node, elapsedTime in
        let timePassed = elapsedTime - lastElapsedTime
        node.position.x += timePassed * speed
        lastElapsedTime = elapsedTime
    }
}
```

The initial implementation seems deceivingly simple, however, problems start to emerge when you consider what happens if the same instance of this `SKAction` is executed multiple times by the same node, but with different start times.

Eg.

```swift
let move = SKAction.moveX(by: 5.0, duration: 1)
node.run(.group[move, .sequence[.wait(forDuration: 0.25), move]])
```

In this situation, the `lastElapsedTime` variable breaks as it is being written to two times while running on the same node *(I'm aware this problem exists even when running the on different nodes. However, I managed to get around this problem by using Key-Value pairs. So it isn't a concern)*. In such situations the `timePassed` won't be accurate.

Does anyone know how I can implement this custom action and have it work even if the same instance runs on the same node at different times? Keep in mind the spacing between `elapsedTime` isn't the same as the timing mode isn't always linear. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can. The builtin `move` action is definitely not implemented with `customAction`, since `move` is reversible. It is highly likely that it is implemented with some private APIs.

Comment: @Sweeper That is heartbreaking to hear because I spent the entire day trying to figure this out :'( Is there no way to create a custom action that is up to the standard of a built-in action? Eg. Having effects compound, have it be shared among different nodes, etc. I managed to get all of these to work but always had to make some sort of sacrifice. Just got me wondering if custom actions can ever be up to that standard.

Comment: How about just calling `moveX` twice? Sure it's not the same as the built-in ones, but it does "compound". :-)

Answer (score 1):

As you have found out, the reason why your attempt doesn't work is because there is only one `lastElapsedTime`. As soon as the second action (the one that starts after 0.25 seconds) starts, the single `lastElapsedTime` variable gets overwritten with the elapsed time of the second action.

In other words, your closure is simultaneously fed the elapsed time of both the first and the second action, and you cannot distinguish which one it is.

A simple way to fix this is to not reuse the `move` action twice. Create two of them.

```
let move1 = SKAction.moveX(by: 5.0, duration: 1)
let move2 = SKAction.moveX(by: 5.0, duration: 1)
node.run(.group([move1, .sequence([.wait(forDuration: 0.25), move2]])))
```

Now there are *two* `lastElapsedTime`s.

The built in `move` is not implemented using `customAction`. Compare the types that are created by these methods:

```
type(of: SKAction.moveBy(x: 100, y: 100, duration: 1)) // SKMove
type(of: SKAction.customAction(withDuration: 1, actionBlock: { _, _ in })) // SKCustomAction
```

You can find the headers of these here: [SKMove.h](https://developer.limneos.net/index.php?ios=15.2.1&framework=SpriteKit.framework&header=SKMove.h) [SKCustomAction.h](https://developer.limneos.net/index.php?ios=15.2.1&framework=SpriteKit.framework&header=SKCustomAction.h). They respectively have `SKCMove` and `SKCCustomAction` as their members.

There seems to be such a class for every built-in action. It is possible that the factories in `SKAction` just calls the factories in these class.

I have also found that there is a method in `SKCMove` called `cpp_updateWithTargetForTime(SKCNode*, double)`. This also seems to be in all the action classes prefixed `SKC`. Presumably, the actual implementation of how the action is performed is written in this method.

That method probably can access things that our code cannot, including but not limited to, the time since the last frame, and so is able to calculate how much the node should move.

Technically, you can get the time since last frame in your scene too, like this:

```
// in MyScene
var timeSinceLastFrame: Double = 0
var lastFrame: Double?
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if let lastFrame = self.lastFrame {
        timeSinceLastFrame = currentTime - lastFrame
    }
    lastFrame = currentTime
}
```

Then you can write a `moveX` method that works very similarly to the built-in one, but only in `MyScene`.

```
static func moveX(by amount: CGFloat, duration: CGFloat) -> SKAction {
    let speed = amount / duration
    return .customAction(withDuration: duration) { node, elapsedTime in
        if elapsedTime > 0 {
            let timePassed = (node.scene as! MyScene).timeSinceLastFrame
            node.position.x += timePassed * speed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the info. I managed to get everything working by using an array for `lastElapsedTime` and finding the value in that array closest but still lower than the current `elapsedTime`. The `lastElapsedTime` array only *grows* when `elapsedTime == 0`. I haven't tested it thoroughly yet but it's been working so far

Comment: @rayaantaneja You're welcome to post that as an answer! :) So `elapsedTime` always start at 0? I'm not sure if you can rely on that...

Comment: You were right about that. I changed the logic for it slightly. Will post the code once it's more concrete